# Cauchy principal value is a tempered distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

In an example in Reed & Simon's book on functional analysis they prove that the Cauchy principal part integral
$$\mathscr{P}\Big(\frac1x\Big): f \mapsto \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{|x|\geq \epsilon} \frac1x f(x) dx \tag{1}$$
is a tempered distribution.

Let $f \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^1)$ (a Schwarz function). They first rewrite the integral in (1) as
$$\int_{|x|\geq \epsilon} \frac1x f(x) dx = \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{x}dx.$$
They then say that since $[f(x)-f(-x)]/x \rightarrow 2f'(0)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, we can write
$$\mathscr{P}\Big(\frac1x\Big)(f) = \int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)- f(-x)}{x}dx$$
which proves it is finite. I understand everything until this point.

From here, they say since
$$\left|\frac{1}{x}[f(x) - f(-x)]\right| \leq \frac1x\int_{-x}^x|f'(t)|dt \leq 2 \|f'\|_\infty \tag{2}$$
we have
$$\left| \mathscr{P}\left(\frac1x\right)(f)\right| \leq 2 \int_0^1\|f'\|_\infty dx + \left|\int_1^\infty(xf(x))\frac{dx}{x^2}\right| \leq 2\|f\|_{1,0} + \|f\|_{0,1}. \tag{3}$$
Thus $\mathscr{P}(1/x)$ is a distribution.

Here they are using the notation
$$\|\varphi\|_{\alpha, \beta} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |x^\alpha D^\beta \varphi(x)| $$
to be the seminorm on $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I do not understand how they establish the inequalities in (3) or how they follow from (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$g(x) = \frac{f(x)- f(-x)}{x}$$
We have
$$
\begin{align}
\|f\|_{1,0} &= \sup_{x\in\Bbb{R}} |xf(x)|\\
\|f\|_{0,1} &= \sup_{x\in\Bbb{R}} |f'(x)| = \|f'\|_\infty
\end{align}
$$
by $(2)$
$$|g(x)| \le 2 \|f\|_{0,1}$$
for $x>0$.  So
$$\left|\int_0^1 g(x)dx\right|\le \int_0^1 |g(x)|dx \le 1\cdot 2 \|f\|_{0,1} = 2 \|f\|_{0,1}$$
Also for $x>0$
$$|g(x)| \le \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| + \left|\frac{f(-x)}{x}\right|$$
So
$$\left|\int_1^\infty g(x)dx\right|\le \int_1^\infty |g(x)|dx \le \int_1^\infty \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|dx + \int_1^\infty \left|\frac{f(-x)}{x}\right|dx$$
Now
$$\int_1^\infty \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|dx = \int_1^\infty \left|\frac{xf(x)}{x^2}\right|dx \le \|f\|_{1,0} \int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} = \|f\|_{1,0}\cdot 1 = \|f\|_{1,0}$$
and similarly
$$\int_1^\infty \left|\frac{f(-x)}{x}\right|dx\le \|f\|_{1,0}$$
so
$$\int_1^\infty |g(x)|dx \le 2 \|f\|_{1,0}$$
and altogether
$$\left|\int_0^\infty g(x)dx\right| \le \int_0^\infty |g(x)|dx \le 2 \|f\|_{0,1} + 2 \|f\|_{1,0}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Their final inequality has $2\|f\|_{1,0} + \|f\|_{0,1}$ as opposed to $2\|f\|_{1,0} + 2\|f\|_{0,1}$, I am wondering if this is a typo in the book or if the inequality you showed can be made sharper.

Comment: @CBBAM:  It's a mistake in $(3)$ because notice that $(3)$ completely ignores the values of $f(x)$ for $x < -1$.  This is impossible, because $f(x)$ for $x < -1$ is independent of $f(x)$ for $x > 1$.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help.